# With Scala + sbt, how do you simultaneously allow IntelliJ builds and command line builds?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'd like to be able to build using sbt, both inside IntelliJ and from a command line.  How do I do that?  The default appears to be to have both of those use the same directories for object files, and the two builds often clash.  I'm fine having them just build two completely independent sets of output files in different directories.

(I often want to start up a command line and do something like ~publishM2, while still doing things like run tests inside Intellij.)

I'm using IntelliJ 2016.1.1.

Comment: You can manually do a 'Rebuild...' in IntelliJ or a 'clean' in the sbt console; this works but makes compile times slower (due to by-passing incremental compilation). It's tedious but it works and that's how I do it currently.

Alternatively you could try to experiment with the Compiler output directory settings in IntelliJ; check out File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> (select a module) -> Paths tab. Not sure if it will work, especially not sure if it will reset to the default when you update your build.sbt file.

Comment: The manual things are what's causing the problem; I have a continuous build running from the command line, so building from inside Intellij just causes problems.

Comment: I think you might be right about changing paths in the paths tab - I'm giving it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

(Update: I think this is only better than just letting both systems use the same output path.  See comments for lock issues, and settings on this page don't appear to be saved - you need to do this every time you launch.)

Thanks to @PermaFrost, I think you can just change the output paths for Intellij in  File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> (select a module) -> Paths tab, like this:

[image]

Comment: even if this helps, sbt has many problems in running more than one process at same time. If I try to compile 2 different projects in 2 different folders, I will continually receive something like `Waiting for lock on ~/repository/.sbt.ivy.lock to be available...`

Comment: In my experience this waiting for the lock file only happens when you update libraryDependencies and such. Most of the time it will get the lock at some point and work just fine, I've only rarely see it lock up indefinitely on this. But your mileage may vary.

Comment: Using coursier avoids the global ivy lock